# Two classes making same instance?? java

Tags: java, class, object, instance, inner-classes

so i had this exam in university which was to create book class which would have author, title, content and translator.

main requirement was to create only 1 class and create inner classes within it (author and translator)

and one Main class to test it.

Problem was that when i created author and translator objects and tried to change their names, both of them would change names.

Here's my code:

Book Class:

```
public class Book {
    private Author author;
    private Translator translator;
    private String title;
    private String text;

    public interface IPerson {
        public void setFirstName(String name);
        public String getFirstName();
        public void setLastName(String name);
        public String getLastName();
    }
    //Author
    public class Author implements IPerson{
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Author(String f, String l){
            firstName = f;
            lastName = l;
            author = this;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String name){
            this.firstName = name;
        }

        public String getFirstName(){
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String name){
            this.lastName = name;
        }

        public String getLastName(){
            return this.lastName;
        }

    }
    public Author getAuthor(){
        return this.author;
    }
    //Translator
    public class Translator extends Author{

        public Translator(String f, String l) {
            super(f, l);
            translator = this;
        }
    }
    public Translator getTranslator(){
        return this.translator;
    }
    public String getTranslatorFullName(){
        return this.getTranslator().getFirstName() + " " + this.getTranslator().getLastName();
    }
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDisplayTitle(){
        return getTitle() + " Author: " + this.getAuthor().getFirstName() + " " + this.getAuthor().getLastName();
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Book mybook = new Book();
    mybook.setTitle("Fight Club");
    mybook.setText("First rule of Fight Club, you do not talk about Fight Club");
    Book.Author author = mybook.new Author("John","Doe");
    Book.Translator translator = mybook.new Translator("Alan","Rickman");
    System.out.println(mybook.getDisplayTitle());
    System.out.println(mybook.getAuthor().getLastName());
    System.out.println(mybook.getAuthor().getFirstName());
    System.out.println(mybook.getTranslatorFullName());
    System.out.println(mybook.getTranslator().getFirstName());
}
}
```

It Had to pass these tests, what was my problem?

**Don't tell me to make Translator implement IPerson, it was my teachers request to extend**

Comment: In your Translator constructor you have super(f, l); and in Author's constructor you have translator = this;, so when creating Translator when the super is called in Author;s constructor you will replace old Author so in the end you will have both them set with the values of Translator instance

Comment: check the super(f,l), you pass the translators name to the super class which is the author so definitely both of them get the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```
public Author(String f, String l, boolean authorCheck){
    firstName = f;
    lastName = l;
    if(authorCheck)
    {
        author = this;
    }
}

public Author(String f, String l){
    firstName = f;
    lastName = l;
    author = this;
}
```

---

```
public Translator(String f, String l) {
    super(f, l, false);
    translator = this;
}
```

Comment: yeah that's good idea but i can't change the Main class, so what do i do?

Comment: @nikagar4 you don't have to change the main class. I updated my answer. Leave the old constructor and add the new one I proposed. You can have both because it is overloaded. Just call the `super` with the `boolean` for `Translator`...

Comment: @nikagar4 does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense if `Translator` implements `IPerson` instead of extending `Author`.

Comment: yeah i know but request was to make extend instead of implements

Answer (score 0):

You're making a `super(f,l)` call in the constructor of `Translator`. `Translator` is changing the `Author` fields as the superclass of `Translator` is `Author`.

Comment: OK i've considered that, i didn't knew how to change it and by the way setName would also change both of them

Comment: not all Translators are Authors, so it should not be an inheritance relationship. You can make Translator implement IPerson

Comment: i agree that translator should implement iperson but the request was to make extend